# Installing Mathematica 11.3

Tags: raspbian-stretch, wolfram-engine

Having found I had Mathematica 11.0 installed on one Pi and needing to move it 11.3 as on the rest of my cluster I've found apt-get install won't install it, but there is a script at http://www.wolfram.com/raspberry-pi/ which will download the .deb package. However, using dkpg as suggested yields

sudo dpkg -i /tmp/wolfram-engine-install/wolfram-engine_11.3.0+2018052403_armhf.deb

(Reading database ... 146001 files and directories currently installed.)

Preparing to unpack .../wolfram-engine_11.3.0+2018052403_armhf.deb ...

wolfram-eula license has already been accepted

Unpacking wolfram-engine (11.3.0+2018052403) over (11.0.1+2017031701) ...

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wolfram-engine:

wolfram-engine depends on libhunspell-1.4-0; however:
  Package libhunspell-1.4-0 is not installed.

wolfram-engine depends on libssl1.0.2; however:
  Package libssl1.0.2 is not installed.

wolfram-engine depends on coinor-libipopt1v5; however:
  Package coinor-libipopt1v5 is not installed.

wolfram-engine depends on libraw15; however:
  Package libraw15 is not installed.

wolfram-engine depends on libexiv2-14; however:
  Package libexiv2-14 is not installed.

.....

To get over the dependencies I tried

gdebi /tmp/wolfram-engine-install/wolfram-engine_11.3.0+2018052403_armhf.deb

but that failed with

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 
Building data structures... Done 
This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: libhunspell-1.4-0

Finally, I installed hunspell by hand which reported as its version

@(#) International Ispell Version 3.2.06 (but really Hunspell 1.7.0)

But still Mathematica will not install! Any ideas on how to fix this please? I am running Stretch and I have done all the usual apt-get update .. etc.

Comment: On Stretch either update/upgrade (if Mathematica is already installed or update/install (if not yet installed) should work. Is the RPF Repo in your apt sources (check /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mea culpa! I was running Jessie. Updated it according  to https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspbian-stretch/ which fixed the problem, though I had to use apt-get purge wolfram-engine and then reinstall wolfram using apt-get install wolfram-engine. Thanks to @Dirk for the hint about raspi.list.

Still had a problem hanging over from the attempt to install under Jessie, libpcre16.3 was missing and I had to copy a version from another install by hand but Mathematica seems to be now up and running.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.